# Elasticsearch - bulk post data

Tags: rest, elasticsearch

(ES amateur here) I am using the [Elasticsearch Bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) through Jenkins (Groovy) to post multiple documents at once to an index. However, the following request in groovy only reads the first row of data and ignores the 5 other lines below it.

```
httpRequest url: "https://elasticsearchindex.url/here",
            httpMode: 'POST',
            contentType: 'APPLICATION_JSON',
            requestBody: "{\"hostname\" : \"playground.test\",\"postDate\" : \"2021-11-22T20:23:00\",\"device_id\" : \"${osList[0][0]}\",\"rule_name\" : \"${osList[0][1]}\",\"policy_name\" : \"${policyName}${osList[0][2]}\",\"rule_id\": \"${osList[0][3]}\"}\
                          {\"hostname\" : \"playground.test\",\"postDate\" : \"2021-11-22T20:23:00\",\"device_id\" : \"${osList[1][0]}\",\"rule_name\" : \"${osList[1][1]}\",\"policy_name\" : \"${policyName}${osList[1][2]}\",\"rule_id\": \"${osList[1][3]}\"}\
                          {\"hostname\" : \"playground.test\",\"postDate\" : \"2021-11-22T20:23:00\",\"device_id\" : \"${osList[2][0]}\",\"rule_name\" : \"${osList[2][1]}\",\"policy_name\" : \"${policyName}${osList[2][2]}\",\"rule_id\": \"${osList[2][3]}\"}\
                          {\"hostname\" : \"playground.test\",\"postDate\" : \"2021-11-22T20:23:00\",\"device_id\" : \"${osList[3][0]}\",\"rule_name\" : \"${osList[3][1]}\",\"policy_name\" : \"${policyName}${osList[3][2]}\",\"rule_id\": \"${osList[3][3]}\"}\
                          {\"hostname\" : \"playground.test\",\"postDate\" : \"2021-11-22T20:23:00\",\"device_id\" : \"${osList[4][0]}\",\"rule_name\" : \"${osList[4][1]}\",\"policy_name\" : \"${policyName}${osList[4][2]}\",\"rule_id\": \"${osList[4][3]}\"}\
                          {\"hostname\" : \"playground.test\",\"postDate\" : \"2021-11-22T20:23:00\",\"device_id\" : \"${osList[5][0]}\",\"rule_name\" : \"${osList[5][1]}\",\"policy_name\" : \"${policyName}${osList[5][2]}\",\"rule_id\": \"${osList[5][3]}\"}"
```

Not sure if the API here is built for what I'm trying to do, or if I am writing it incorrectly. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Hey, just look at the documentation, your payload is not respecting the layout needed. And you are not calling the right endpoint for bulk ingestion. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html

Comment: @Paulo I specified my index in the URL thinking that would render the need for lines like this { "index": { "_id": "london" }} to be unnecessary. Is that not possible here because endpoint should end with '/_bulk'? 

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can post data like below using curl

```
curl -XPOST -u username:pass https://elasticsearchserver:9200/company/branch/_bulk -d'
    { "index": { "_id": "london" }}
    { "name": "London Westminster", "city": "London", "country": "UK" }
    { "index": { "_id": "liverpool" }}
    { "name": "Liverpool Central", "city": "Liverpool", "country": "UK" }
    { "index": { "_id": "paris" }}
    { "name": "Champs Élysées", "city": "Paris", "country": "France" }
'
```

That should give you output of creation.

[image]

Comment: Apologies I forgot to mention I was doing this through groovy jenkins. But I will translate your curl into groovy to see if it works!

Comment: I specified my index in the URL thinking that would render the need for lines like this { "index": { "_id": "london" }} to be unnecessary. Is that not possible here because endpoint should end with '/_bulk'